# How can I allow USB debugging from a new computer when I have a broken screen?

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

I am able to access my Android phone via "USB debugging" from one computer.  I'd like to allow a second computer the same privilege, but when I plug it in there it says "device unauthorized".

How can I allow USB debugging from a new computer when I have a broken screen?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if you use scrcpy "tcp ip" mode to connect to it, then connect via USB to the "other computer" you can use the first device to click "allow access" on the phone, then it can connect to the second device USB.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can...

- Use an external keyboard and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the `Allow` button then accept.
- Mirror your screen to a working display, e.g., via MHL cable, QGeeM hub, Samsung SideSync, etc.
- On phones with independent touch and stylus digitizers (namely the Samsung Note series), even if one is broken the other may still be functional (often the touch digitizer breaks more easily than the stylus one).